# CSS: align element to the right end of its container

Tags: html, css, alignment

### Goal

Inside a form, I want to align my row-based fields so that the title of the field is left-aligned, but the `input`s are right-aligned.

My form looks like this

```html
<form class="settings", id="settings", onsubmit="OnSubmit();">
    <label class="section-title">Basic</label>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <section class="setting">
        <div class="field">
            <span class="field-title">Name: </span>
            <span class="entry-group">
                <label class="entry-underlined">
                    <input name="myfield" class="entry" type="number" min="1024", max="65535", placeholder="12345" required>
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
    .....

<form/>
```

So for example, I'd love the `span.field-title` to left align, but the `input` "myfield" to right align.

### Attempts

I've tried many solutions such as `flex` and `align-content`, but none worked for me, including

```css
input.entry {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]

### Question

I need a general direction and working solution of such tasks because it seems an area to revisit often.

Comment: I see the label and input are aligned left and right, so what is it you needed? those 2 should stay close?

Comment: @Manjuboyz no, they should be reasonably apart but all the entries on the right side should align with the right edge of the page, all the labels on the left should align with the left edge. They still stick together on my page.

Comment: @Manjuboyz the `label` element is not what I want to align left, it's the `span`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this??

```css
.field {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<form class="settings" , id="settings" , onsubmit="OnSubmit();">
  <label class="section-title">Basic</label>
  <div class="separator"></div>

  <section class="setting">
    <div class="field">
      <span class="field-title">Name: </span>
      <span class="entry-group">
                <label class="entry-underlined">
                    <input name="myfield" class="entry" type="number" min="1024", max="65535", placeholder="12345" required>
                </label>
            </span>
    </div>
  </section>


  <form/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried your code, but to my surprise, on my page (Electron) they are still together. See my updated question.

Comment: @kakyo you don't have to use this code `input.entry {..}` so I am pretty much sure my code should work fine if not I believe there is some other code overriding the current one. fiddler for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/6wy1dja5/

Comment: OK, that did the trick. Indeed I was trying to fill the code into my `input.entry` and that didn't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the input-field to be aligned right or the input value text?

Check this very basic example

```css
input[type=number] {
  text-align:right;
}

.field2 {
  width:500px;
  background:grey;
}

.entry2 {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<form class="settings", id="settings", onsubmit="OnSubmit();">
    <label class="section-title">Basic</label>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <section class="setting">
        <div class="field">
            <span class="field-title">Name: </span>
            <span class="entry-group">
                <label class="entry-underlined">
                    <input name="myfield" class="entry" type="number" min="1024", max="65535", placeholder="12345" required>
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
    .....

</form>

<form class="settings", id="settings", onsubmit="OnSubmit();">
    <label class="section-title">Basic</label>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <section class="setting">
        <div class="field2">
            <span class="field-title">Name: </span>
            <span class="entry-group">
                <label class="entry-underlined">
                    <input name="myfield" class="entry2" type="number" min="1024", max="65535", placeholder="12345" required>
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
    .....

</form>
```